# SQL: sum function returns a different result once I use it in a Join

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, inner-join

In BigQuery SQL, when I use the sum function while joining 2 tables, the sum results are incorrect as it is performing a cartesian product. I am not sure how to change the code so that when joining the tables, this does not happen.

Here are screenshots of the tables that I'm using:

`daily_activity` table

[image: daily_activity table]

`sleep_day` table

[image: sleep_day table]

When I write out this code:

```sql
SELECT
  DISTINCT(Id),
  SUM(TotalSteps) AS sum_total_steps
FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.daily_activity` 
GROUP BY Id
ORDER BY sum_total_steps DESC;
```

I get the correct sum of total steps for each `Id`.

[image: Screenshot]

But when I use the code below, the `sum_total_steps` results are different and incorrect (the `sum_minutes_asleep` is also incorrect).

```sql
SELECT
  (DA.Id),
  SUM(DA.TotalSteps) AS sum_total_steps,
  SUM(SD.TotalMinutesAsleep) AS sum_minutes_asleep
FROM `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.daily_activity` AS DA
JOIN `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.sleep_day` AS SD
ON DA.Id = SD.Id
GROUP BY DA.Id;
```

The sums have now changed.

[image: Screenshot]

I cannot figure out why the sums are different for the second code. It seems like the second code is performing a cartesian product for the sums and I'm not sure how to adjust the code.

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you actually look at the data in the tables, you will see that ID is not unique per row but appears to be a user ID.  Since it appears you are looking for a per-user summary, I would recommend this:

```
with
    da as (
        select id, sum(TotalSteps) as sum_total_steps
        from `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.daily_activity`
        group by id
    )
    sa as (
        select id, sum(TotalMinutesAsleep) as sum_minutes_asleep
        from `bellabeat-case-study-385200.fitbit_data.sleep_day`
        group by id
    )
select
    coalesce(da.id, sa.id) as id,
    da.sum_total_steps,
    sa.sum_minutes_asleep
from
    da
    full outer join 
    sa on sa.id = da.id
```

Since the tables each have ID repeated over multiple dates, but you do not include the date in you join, you are in essence doing a "mini cartesian" join, where it's cartesian product for each ID, rather than a full cartesian product of both tables.

Comment: The initial code you gave me produced the result that I was looking for where I had to join the tables by both the Id and Dates. I wanted to see how this updated code performed since I am trying to use WITH to create a temp table for a different problem of mine and I get the same error for the code you provided as the ones I am getting on my own. The error is: Syntax error: Expected "(" or "," or keyword SELECT but got identifier "sa" at [7:5]. I keep getting this error as well after the initial WITH statement